# Raspberry Camera on Kodi

Tags: camera

I am trying to install a raspberry camera V2 8mp on a new raspberry pi 3 running LibreELEC Kodi. Can it be done from Kodi or should I reinstall Raspbian?

Comment: I had bookmarked this a few weeks back to look into more at some future time so not sure if it will work or fit your needs.  It is under OpenELEC on github.  [PICAMERA](https://github.com/OpenELEC/unofficial-addons/pull/60)

Comment: I get the message "this is a console only addon"

Comment: Have you found someway to get it in Openelec Kodi S.O ??

Answer (score 0):

LibreELEC [appears to have the Picamera Python package](https://github.com/LibreELEC/LibreELEC.tv/blob/ff6a40d5efdf6fe78879885ae30a0db351c7f4be/packages/addons/addon-depends/rpi-tools-depends/picamera/package.mk) as a built-in add-on, which should be available through the System -> Settings -> Add-ons menu. That package includes a dependency on the camera driver, so it *should* 'just work'.

Comment: I get the message "this is a console only addon" where is the console? Thanks

Comment: You'll need to use SSH from another machine. See: https://wiki.libreelec.tv/index.php?title=Accessing_LibreELEC .